# Genova palaces and Greek Gods

Tags: italy, greece, history, genoa

In via Garibaldi 12, in the main hall, I saw 4 Gods: Zeus, Hermes, Athena and one more, which I didn't recognize. Maybe it could be Hera, since was looking at her husband (checking on him..).

[image]

Who is that (Greek?) God(dess)?

Comment: We have a [Mythology site](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/). It might be better to ask there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to travel, except insofar as the asker found the statue somewhere other than in their home.

Comment: It's not difficult to first rotate a picture, crop it and then upload it. But the question is not about travel, I could post the image of any obscure statue in Italy and ask someone to name me the sculptor, and the year it was sculpted.